# Keep 10 item in dimensional array in Redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

i have a state in redux that it has Two dimensions
1.user id and 2.product id

```
return {
  ...state,
  [action.payload.user.id]: {
    ...state[action.payload.user.id],
    [action.payload.product.id]: {
      data: action.payload.product
    }
  }
}
```

i want to keep last 10 product for each user in my state

please help me ? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

When ever, you are adding new product to user, you get the last 9 (upto) and add the new one. Use `slice(-9)` will give last 9 items in array.

Update: as @JakubKotrs pointed out, Updating to maintain as array of products for user.

```
return {
  ...state,
  [action.payload.user.id]: [
    ...state[action.payload.user.id].slice(-9),
    {
      [action.payload.product.id]: {
        data: action.payload.product,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: This would not work, you're calling `slice` on what seems to be an object rather than an array.

Comment: Oh, you are right @JakubKotrs and Thanks for correcting it. I will update the answer

Comment: thank u for your attention but slice does not work here:(